# “NetworkManager is not running”- error. After manually upgrading nmcli to 1.0.6 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management, network-manager

I need to use the new version of NetworkManager on ubuntu 12.04.
I've installed NetworkManager-1.0.6 from source code, [from gnome Projects web site](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager)
(And allot of it's dependencies).

After installation,

I tried to run:

```
$ nmcli connection
Error: NetworkManager is not running.
```

then I tried:

```
$ service network-manager start
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call",
sender=":1.156" (uid=1000 pid=9473 comm="start network-manager ") 
interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="
(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 
pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

$ service network-manager status
network-manager stop/waiting
```

As root it appears that the network-manager start running but it's still stays in the same status:

```
$ sudo service network-manager start
network-manager start/running, process 9975

$ sudo service network-manager status
network-manager stop/waiting
```

What can I check ?
How can I make it work ?
Should I install/update the network-manager in a different way?

Answer (score 12):

Open your terminal, type:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

Reference: http://www.necopost.com/2012/06/network-manager-not-running-error-on.html

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 2):

If the issue on your system (tested on Ubuntu 20.04) is like this:

```
$ sudo systemctl status NetworkManager  

- NetworkManager.service  
- Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit NetworkManager.service is masked.)  
- Active: inactive (dead)
```

Try the below steps:

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask NetworkManager.service  

- Removed `/etc/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service`.
```

The below command will help you to connect to the internet using ethernet:

```
$ sudo dhclient <your_ethernet_device>

- ethernet device can be found using the `ifconfig -a`  
- It will take a few minutes for the command to finish.
```

Now run the below command to reinstall network manager

```
$ sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

And now you can see your WiFi and ethernet back.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot run launch a daemon without root access using `Upstart` (the init daemon of Ubuntu). Moreover, the `network-manager` program needs root access as its goal is to allow regular user access to the network (which is restricted to root user in most Unix systems).

As for your problem, you need to find out where the problem come from. You can try to have a look in the logs (`/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/messages.log` on Ubuntu 12.04). Another option is to launch the application and see the error message, by running directly `network-manager` daemon from your shell:

```
sudo /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
```

Also, did you remove the ubuntu `network-manager` package before installing from source? And how did you install it from source?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried now to run the network-manager deamon and got:
   `$ cat: /var/log/messages.log: No such file or directory`

I downloaded the source code, extracted and compiled with :
`$ ./configure && make && sudo make install`


I removed with `sudo apt-get remove network-manager*`

Comment: The file is actually `/var/log/messages`. You should open it with `less` as it is probably a big file. Also you might need root rights depending on your configuration.

Comment: This is missing either.
`sudo less /var/log/messages.
/var/log/messages.: No such file or directory`

Comment: Then try to find a log available. `sudo ls -l /var/log`. Here is a doc to see each log function: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles. You may want to look for a file named `syslog` or `everything`.

Comment: At first it was looking for a .conf file, so I have touched a .conf file where he was looking for.
and when I run i get this error in the syslog.
`$ cat /var/log/syslog`

`Aug 31 17:52:54 shlomi-PC kernel: [28326.161479] NetworkManager[16105]: segfault at 20 ip 00007f86035a1076 sp 00007ffc59b18120 error 4 in libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4[7f860355b000+f2000]`

can I do something with it ?

Comment: As I was expected, your version of glib is too old. My suggestion is never install a package from source unless you know what you are doing. The package maintainer should be the one who updates the package, as he knows those kind of compatibility issues. If you really need network-manager 1.0.6, I suggest using a distribution that provides it, like ArchLinux. Some other distribution might provides a recent version of network manager too, but 1.0.6 just came out so you will only find it in rolling release distribution or testing repositories.

Comment: I need at least version 1.0.0 and on ubuntu 12.04.
Apparently I cant find such an option...

Comment: According to Gentoo building tree, network-manager 1.0.0 requires glib 2.32 (https://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/net-misc/networkmanager/networkmanager-1.0.0.ebuild?view=markup). You should go through all the packages listed in my link and find out if the version are OK. Also I am surprised that you were able to build... If you still have problems after trying network manager 1.0.0 you'll need to investigate the stack of the segfault.